# What are the return values for the mybatis update functions?

Tags: java, mybatis, mybatis-generator

We're using MyBatis 3.0.6 to work with our database.

The MyBatis generator will automatically generate 4 **updateByXYZ()** methods. Each of these methods returns an int.

I've been digging all over but can't find any documentation telling me what possible values are returned from these methods. Anybody know?

Comment: either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's the number of records affected(updated or deleted)

Comment: Thanks! But can you provide a link?

Comment: @Kricket https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/java-api.html#statement-execution-methods